# Django channels create a async count down

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I'm trying to code a website like Gartic.io. I am using django channels as backend django websocket. But I don't know how to do a 30 second countdown async. I need this countdown to control the duration of each drawing round.

I have an async function as `handle_turn(self,room)`. And it handles turns. It calls my **timer** function after some checks like 2 or more player, which raund is it...

What I tried

```
async def timer(self,room):
        try:
            print('1') # check if there is an event loop
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            loop.run_until_complete(self.handle_timer(room))

        except RuntimeError as e:
            print('2') # create a new event loop if there is no event loop
            if str(e).startswith('There is no current event loop in thread'): 
                print('3')
                loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
                asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
                asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(self.handle_timer(room))
            else:
                raise
    
    async def handle_timer(self,room):
        while room.duration > 0:
            await asyncio.sleep(1) # wait for 1 second
            await self.drop_duration(room) # drop duration by -1        
            print('duration is ' + str(room.duration)) # print duration

            if room.duration == 0: # time is up for turn
                await self.reset_duration(room) # reset duration to 30
```

**I got an error**

```
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
```